# critical points of the function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Find the critical points of the function

$$f(x,y)=(4x-x^2)\cos y$$

first let's determinate Partial derivatives:

$$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)=(4-2x)\cos y$$
$$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)=-\sin y(4x-x^2) $$

To find the critical points, we solve:

\begin{cases}\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)=0 & \\
\\
\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)=0 & \end{cases}

\begin{cases}
(4-2x)\cos y=0 & \\
\\
-\sin y(4x-x^2)=0 & \end{cases}

\begin{cases}
(4-2x)\cos y=0 & \\
\\
(x^2-4x)\sin y=0 & \end{cases}

which gives

$  \begin{cases}
4-2x=0 & \\
\\
x^2-4x=0 & \end{cases} \textrm{or} 
 \begin{cases}
4-2x=0 & \\
\\
\sin y=0 & \end{cases}
\textrm{or}
 \begin{cases}
\cos y=0 & \\
\\
x^2-4x=0 & \end{cases}
\textrm{or}
 \begin{cases}
\cos y=0 & \\
\\
\sin y=0 & \end{cases} $

let's treat each case individually

- $  \begin{cases}
  4-2x=0 & \\
  \\
  x^2-4x=0 & \end{cases} \implies \begin{cases}
  x=2 & \\
  \\
  x=0 \textrm{ or } x=4 & \end{cases}  $ thus The system does not have solution
- $ \begin{cases}
  4-2x=0 & \\
  \\
  \sin y=0 & \end{cases} \implies  \begin{cases}
  x=2 & \\
  \\
  \ y=k\pi,\ k \in \mathbb{Z} & \end{cases} \implies (2,k\pi )  $
- $\begin{cases}
  \cos y=0 & \\
  \\
  x^2-4x=0 & \end{cases}\implies \begin{cases}
   y=\dfrac{\pi}{2}+k\pi, \ k \in \mathbb{Z} & \\
  \\
  x=0 \textrm{ or } x=4 & \end{cases}\implies (0,\dfrac{\pi}{2}+k\pi) \textrm{ or } (4,\dfrac{\pi}{2}+k\pi)$
- $\begin{cases}
  \cos y=0 & \\
  \\
  \sin y=0 & \end{cases} \implies$ thus The system does not have solution

The function has three critical points $$(2,k\pi ), (0,\dfrac{\pi}{2}+k\pi) \textrm{ and }(4,\dfrac{\pi}{2}+k\pi)$$

- Am i right ?

Answer (score 2):

1)$(4-2x)\cos y= 0$: The possible Solutions are $x=2,y= \frac{\pi}{2} + \pi n$. $n$ is arbitrary natural number.
2)$(x^2-4x)\sin y = 0$: Possible Solutions: $x=0,x=4,y=\pi n$.

Your critical Points are all possible $x,y$ which satisfy **both** equations. For example, $(x=2,y= \pi(n+ \frac{1}{2}))$ is not a critical Point, because it satisfies 1) but not 2). All critical Points are the points $(x,y)$ where $x$ satisfies either 1) or 2) and $y$ satisfies the other equation (i.e. if $x$ satisfies 1), then $y$ satisfies 2) and if $x$ satisfies 2), then $y$ satisfies 1)).

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The second equation is $x(x-4)\sin y=0$ which gives $x=0$ or $x=4$ or $y=k\pi$, $k \in \Bbb{Z}$.

Consider all three cases separately by plugging them in to the first equation.